# SplFileInfo::getSize not working when the filename has special characters (russian, chinese...)

Tags: php, symfony

I have a function that tries to retrieve the size of my uploaded files, but it's failing when the filename has special characters like french, russian or chinese charaters:

> - 5b99109c1a10e_装配工具大样册.pdf
> - 5b99104337d6b_Kаталог 2016 Русский.pdf
> - 5b99140a5a47d_Brochure CVI3 (Français).pdf

Here is the error:

> SplFileInfo::getSize(): stat failed for C:\wamp\www\DESiwid\app/../web/uploads/documents\5b99104337d6b_Kаталог 2016 Русский.pdf

And here is my code:

```
/**
 * @param Document $document
 * @return int
 */
private function getSize(Document $document)
{
    /* retrieve Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File $file from entity */
    $file = $document->getFileFile();
    /* return file size */
    return $file->getSize();
}
```

Comment: you have to rename the uploads and replace the special characters iguess

Comment: Could this be an encoding issue? Can you get the content from the `$file` object or does that fail as well?

Comment: print more code please : the entity and full methods that you use to upload file .